# CentOS yum parallel downloads

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, yum

I noticed that yum downloads one file at a time in CentOS but in fedora it can download more than one file while updating. Is there a way to modify yum in CentOS to make it perform parallel downloads while updating

Comment: This is almost certainly a version issue. The version of yum in Fedora (whatever version you are looking at) is almost certainly newer than the version of yum in CentOS (whatever version you are looking at). The only way to get the change in the CentOS version of yum would be to find the change in the yum sources and see about back-porting it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? I haven't noticed updating in parallel on Fedora at all. If you're talking of running updates in one terminal and installing in another while both are using yum, that's possible. Though if such doesn't work, I'd assume yum is old on CentOS.

Might be better if you stick to the current main stream linux arches such as Ubuntu and Fedora. I'd assume most support is there at the moment.